# eigenvalue of a specific matrix

Tags: matrices

[image]

I am looking for a way to calculate the eigenvalues of this matrix. the last row contains complex numbers in general.

Comment: Check out [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix). As the article indicates, the name is sometimes also used for the transpose, which you've got here.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix is in controller (not controllable!) canonical form (except for the signs of $i_k$) and
the characteristic polynomial is given by $\det (sI -A) = (-i_1)+(-i_2)s + \cdots + (-i_6) s^5 + s^6$.

Without more information, there is no general form for the eigenvalues.